# Next.js Prop `href` did not match. Server: "/" Client: "/#page3"

Tags: next.js, href, router, i18next

Hi I'm developing a web page using Next.js and using hash to make it work like fullpage.js.
(fullpage.js : https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/ko/#page2)

It's a problem when I refresh the browser and in my opinion, it's because the route path on the server is '/', but on the browser is '/#page3'.

How do I remove this warning?
[image]

The code below is to push the path to the router when scrolling down
[image]

and when the menu is clicked to change language, the hash value is pushed to the router and the browser is refreshed.

```
router.push(router.asPath, router.asPath, { locale: 'en' });
router.reload(router.asPath);
```

Comment: Could you please provide the full code for that page component? It's hard to tell where `router.push` is being used.